# I made mistakes when I was using Python to insert simple data into elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I just touched elastic search, and after some simple tutorials with python, there was an error inserting data. My elastic search version was 6.4.0, and my Python version was 3.6 macOS version was 10.13.6
code:

```
#from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400)

es.index(index="my-index", doc_type="test-type", id=1, body={"any":"data01", "timestamp": datetime.now()})
```

Errors:

> ```
> PUT /my-index/test-type/1 [status:406 request:0.002s]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/kenneth/PycharmProjects/Python核心编程/Elasticsearch/Python对接Elasticsearch/demo.py", line 8, in <module>
>     es.index(index="my-index", doc_type="test-type", id=1, body={"any":"data01", "timestamp": datetime.now()})
>   File "/Users/kenneth/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
>     return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users/kenneth/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 263, in index
>     _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
>   File "/Users/kenneth/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 307, in perform_request
>     status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
>   File "/Users/kenneth/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 93, in perform_request
>     self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
>   File "/Users/kenneth/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 105, in _raise_error
>     raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
> elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(406, 'Content-Type header [] is not supported')
> ```

Comment: This is a statement, not a question. What do you want help with?

Comment: where is the problem and how to solve it?